Dynamically compile .svelte source code to a view (REPL-like component)
Dynamically compile .svelte source code to a view (REPL-like component)
I'm building a REPL-like feature in my SvelteKit app, where users can input .svelte code, and it gets dynamically compiled and rendered.
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import { compile } from 'svelte/compiler';

  export let code = ''; // The Svelte source code to compile and render

  let container: HTMLElement; // Target container for the dynamic component
  let componentInstance: any;

  onMount(() => {
    try {
      if (code) {
        // Compile the source code with the existing options
        const { js, css, warnings } = compile(code, {
          generate: 'client',
          runes: true
        });

        console.log(js.code);
        console.log(css?.code);
        console.log(warnings);

        // Inject CSS into the document head
        if (css && css.code) {
          const style = document.createElement('style');
          style.textContent = css.code;
          document.head.appendChild(style);
        }

        // Dynamically execute the compiled JavaScript code
        const ComponentConstructor = new Function(`${js.code}; return MyComponent;`)();

        console.log(ComponentConstructor);

        // Render the compiled component into the container
        componentInstance = new ComponentConstructor({
          target: container,
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to compile or render Svelte source:', err);
    }

    return () => {
      // Cleanup the dynamically created component instance
      if (componentInstance) {
        componentInstance.$destroy();
      }
    };
  });
</script>

<!-- Target container for dynamic component rendering -->
<div bind:this={container}></div>


I get this error:

[Error] Failed to compile or render Svelte source:
SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal
"svelte/internal/disclose-version". import call expects one or two
arguments. — DynamicRenderer.svelte:3

And when I set the discloseVersion CompileOption to false I get an error saying can't import *.
Regarding security concerns I'm aware that I should use an iframe, but it still gives the same error.
I have also searched for svelte REPL code and found a video that suggest importing the compiled code and then using a web worker, however it was posted 4 years ago, so I'm not sure if it'll work.
Any ideas what I'm missing?

The compiled output is an ES module with imports from the svelte package for internal logic. You either have to employ a bundler (e.g. Rollup) or use an import map to point the imports to a valid URL from which the code can directly be imported (look at the compiled output to see what it is doing).
Constructing a function from the module probably also does not work. You can create a Blob from the source code, create a URL for it via URL.createObjectURL then use a dynamic import() on that to get the module (its default property should contain the component).
